# How to pre-compile my EF Views

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

Here is the story : I had a huge MVC 2 website using Entity Framework 4.0 and a few days ago, I decided to upgrade MVC 2 => MVC 4 and EF4 => EF6 and .NET Framework 4.5.

I did that on a project containing about 150 controllers and more than 300 entities.

Now the project is running, but not as fast as I thought it would be.

I'm using Entity Framework 6.0.2 with EF 5.x DBContext Generator T4. I used the DB Context generator because with EF4 I did Database First.

In the past I used this command line to pre-compile my views.

> "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\EdmGen.exe" /nologo
>   /language:CSharp /mode:ViewGeneration
>   "/inssdl:$(TargetDir)Models/DBModel.ssdl"
>   "/incsdl:$(TargetDir)Models/DBModel.csdl"
>   "/inmsl:$(TargetDir)Models/DBModel.msl"
>   "/outviews:$(ProjectDir)Models/DBModel.Views.cs"
>
> XCOPY "$(TargetDir)Models/DBModel.csdl" "$(ProjectDir)" /R /Y XCOPY
>   "$(TargetDir)Models/DBModel.ssdl" "$(ProjectDir)" /R /Y XCOPY
>   "$(TargetDir)Models/DBModel.msl" "$(ProjectDir)" /R /Y XCOPY
>   "$(TargetDir)Models/SiteWeb.csdl" "$(ProjectDir)" /R /Y XCOPY
>   "$(TargetDir)Models/SiteWeb.ssdl" "$(ProjectDir)" /R /Y XCOPY
>   "$(TargetDir)Models/SiteWeb.msl" "$(ProjectDir)" /R /Y

Now, how do I do the same thing with EF6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use EdmGen to generate views for EF6. One way to go is to use [PowerTools](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ef6-beta-1-tools-first-pass-is-vs-ef-designer-not-power-tools-yet-amp-i-rsquo-m-good-with-that/). I also created a number of [T4 templates](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=Kadluczka&f%5B0%5D.Value=Kadluczka&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=4) (available on VS Gallery) for generating views and [one of them](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/10/17/ef6-codefirst-view-generation-t4-template-for-c-updated-for-ef6-rtm/) is for EF6. Not sure how helpful it will be for you since the EF6 one is targeted at CodeFirst. Finally, I recently published a package on NuGet which allows generating views on the fly and saving them for later - see [this](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/12/14/using-pre-generated-views-without-having-to-pre-generate-views-ef6/) for more details.

btw. Using 5.x DBContext generator feels wrong with EF6 feels wrong. EF Tooling that ships with VS2013 (and a [standalone version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) available for VS2012) uses EF6 templates to generate the code so I am not sure why you use version for EF5 (and am kind of wondering how it even compiles given [this](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/11/10/what-changed-in-the-ef-tooling-in-visual-studio-2013-and-visual-studio-2012-out-of-band/))

Comment: my EF 6.2 based web application was loading in 60 seconds for first time using InteractiveViews library, but when i switched to EF 6.1X and generated views by power tools i was able to reduce time arount 20 to 25 seconds

Comment: Either view generation did not kick in (if you register it after EF had to generate views it won't be invoked at all) or it was the first time when views were generated and saved and subsequent runs should use saved views. Conceptually views generated at compile time are the same as views generated at runtime so there should not be difference in startup time except for the first time when interactive views need to generate the views and save them for subsequent runs (PowerTools/tt templates perform this step at design time)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376465/entity-framework-6-2-very-slow-first-startup-and-efinteractiveviews) is the post explaining the  problem, it was posted by my colleague, @Pawel can you please give it a look, thanks

Comment: I read the related post but I think it is just guessing. I would recommend running the project locally, reproduce the issue, measure, find the bottleneck and then figure out what's going on.