# Entity Framework 6.2 very slow first startup and EFInteractiveViews

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

this topic is already widely discussed on stackoverflow and many other blogs, reason to asking question is that i observe this topic was discussed in mostly 3 to 5 years old posts whereas we have EF 6.2 version now, and i expect this may have updates already (there are more reasons you will find in question.

My application has at least 25 Models(Tables) with MySQL as database, models and relations are configured in OnModelCreating, web site is hosted on godaddy and i do not have good access to IIS configurations etc.

Page load time

- First page load: 65 to 70 seconds
- 2nd page load: 1 to 3 seconds

After 10 minutes delay again it will takes 70 seconds to load page.
Please note that i tested it in different environments, like using different internet connection.
There are no pictures on the page, and test page has only 5 rows of data with two columns (calling simple method db.Test.ToList();)

While searching internet i found that is common problem with EF so i tried fixing it, while taking help from posts [3 Steps for Fast EntityFramework](https://www.fusonic.net/developers/2014/07/09/3-steps-for-fast-entity-framework-6-1-code-first-startup-performance/) and [Pregenerate Model and View Cache](https://www.fusonic.net/developers/2016/04/25/entity-framework-6-pregenerate-model-and-view-cache/#Load-EF-caches)

After this fix

- First page load: 64 to 67 seconds
- 2nd page load: 1 to 3 seconds

  ```
  // DbConfiguration constructor
  public MyDbConfiguration
  {
       var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.GetType().Assembly.Location);
       SetModelStore(new DefaultDbModelStore(path));
  }

  // DbContext
  private static DbMappingViewCacheFactory viewCacheFactory;

  private static DbMappingViewCacheFactory ViewCacheFactory
  {
      get
      {
          if (viewCacheFactory == null)
          {
              var path =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[GlobalContextConfig.EFCacheFolder];
              viewCacheFactory=new FileViewCacheFactory(path+"Budget.Context.MyDbContext.xml");
          }
          return viewCacheFactory;
      }
  }


  public MyDbContext()
      : base("name=MySqlConnectionString")
  {
       // In case i need to update xml for now i delete the old file manually 
      InteractiveViews.SetViewCacheFactory(this, ViewCacheFactory);

      Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);

      this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
      this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
      this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
      this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
  }
  ```

It was improved but not enough, I want to know if these issues are updated in EF 6.2.0 or method of fixing it has changed, or any thing im doing wrong/should check.

I also installed EF 6.1.X and generated views by right clicking Contaxt file and choosing Entity Framework > Generate View in the manu

Results:

- First page load: 40 to 50 seconds
- 2nd page load: 0 to 1.5 seconds

That's quite amazing, EF 6.1.X is much faster than EF 6.2

Build and deployed as Release package with debug=false

For test purpose i also uploaded asp.net application without Entity Framework, it takes 8 to 13 seconds to load for first time, and second load takes in less than 1 seconds

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this issue? 

i have the same problem crushingly slow initial startup.

Comment: If your web is at third party like godaddy then its really hard, I'm still working on it.  if you are hosting locally then it should not take too long. divide context in to multiple contexts like for sales, customers etc. disable debugging, do not use lazy loading, turn off auto detect changes, there are many posts describing different things,

Comment: The main reason of the issue is not only EF, but also the 5-minute idle timeout on any shared-hosting. After 5minutes, your site get stopped and it takes time to start up. My solution for this is using a job scheduler to ping my site url every 4 minutes to keep it always alive. ANd, for the EF performance issue, you can use Model Cache to improve

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know if these issues are updated in EF 6.2.0 or method of fixing it has changed, or any thing im doing wrong/should check.

The answer is yes,

EF 6.2 has introduced a Model Cache

```
public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration() : base()
    {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.GetType().Assembly.Location);
        SetModelStore(new DefaultDbModelStore(path));
    }
}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDbConfiguration))]
public class MyContextContext : DbContext 
{
}
```

You can learn more here: https://codeopinion.com/entity-framework-code-first-model-cache/

Comment: Yes i have been done this configuration too, as i referred to articles,

Comment: Is there some third party tool to handle cache, or level 2nd cache

Comment: The answer depends about what you mean by "to handle cache". To Cache query? to cache the model?

Comment: its about Cache model

Comment: They might have one, but there is none that I know

Comment: @JonathanMagnan I was trying above example but no .xml or .edmx file was created, can you please advise what could be the reason, what should be the file name, if its possible can you please add some code explaining how to set this configuration on dbcontext.  Thanks

Comment: Hello sairfan, I updated the code to include the part to set the configuration.

Comment: File is not created, what could be the reason? thanks

Comment: If you want I look at it, please send a small sample project with this issue here: info@zzzprojects.com

Comment: I was expecting this `this.GetType().Assembly.Location` code was returning bin folder path, but it was not, after passing direct path i was able to see .edmx was created, it only contains model definition, but EF 6 creates file Dbcontaxt.Views.cs which contains sql queries and i observed that makes it way more faster, is there a way we can also create those queries for EF 6.2 as well? thanks (i also sent to my sample project)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you read the performance considerations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/performance-considerations

I am personally struggling with these issues aswell. I resorted to [a) creating custom SQL for some queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql). and b) I created a warmup mechanism. There is also an option to precompile queries which might help.

The warmup mechanism runs at the start of the application on a seperate thread. There it does a very simple request to the database, this forces the creation of the model, and 'triggers' the initial startup delay for all queries. After that query has ran (it takes a couple seconds) a flag gets set. All other operations wait for the flag being set before running. Especially in a multithreaded scenario this helps a lot.

I found out that the startup delay was created per thread. This means that if the delay is let's say 2 seconds, running 3 threads who all create a context and try to run some linq, make the whole application wait for *6 seconds*.

Note that by creating custom queries, one must return all fields for the entity to be created;

```
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); //works
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT [id] FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); //Does not.
```

I have not tested this matter fully - so take some time to test. This is just a heads up.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, my scenario gets even more complex, as I'm working on a site hosted at godaddy where i do not have enough access to IIS configuration at this point ASP.Net becomes garbage, its horribly slow.  It does not make sense to me to use custom queries then why am i using Entity Framework? it would be way  better that i build my own framework for data access it will be only one time effort. what i understand from my experience is that ASP.Net suits only on-premises solutions may be other area are not in their target. as EF Core has same issues means they are not going to fix it.

Comment: "It does not make sense to me to use custom queries then why am i using Entity Framework?" For speed ofcourse! you're exterminating another layer whilst still keeping useful objects in code. Its more about not needing to write validation and filling fields in an object and parsing strings and that kind of stuff.

Comment: I've created a warmup mechanism -- in Application_Start as well as putting it in an ApiController that gets called by a Windows Service on a regular basis. When I execute my query the first time, it's still slow but subsequent calls are fast. Running the warmup mechanism before doing this makes no difference whatsoever. I'm not using SqlQuery like you, but instead am calling .Any() or .FirstOrDefault() on the DbSet associated with my table. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Doing this in multiple threads may cause this behaviour. So thread A starts the query and then thread B starts another query whilst A is not yet fully finished. This could also depend on your EF version btw, this thread is about EF6.2 - newer versions esepecially EF core may have different behaviour. Then the rest really depends on your implementation so its hard to say for me right now. Check the sql profiler is your .Any() acutally firing sql at the database? what is your context model, do you create a new on each time?