# From Entity Framework 4 to Entity Framework 6.3. Slow Startup

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, startup

I have a project in ASP.NET (no ASP.NET Core) based on .NET Framework 4.5 and Entity Framework 4.0.
I'm finishing the transition to Entity Framework 6.3 but I noticed that the startup time is over 1 minute. After startup the website is responsive, even more than before.

My project has a couple of hundred tables.

Entity Frameworks (greater than EF4) have a longer startup time?
What could I do to reduce startup time?

Comment: I doubt anyone remembers what EF 4 was like. It definitely wasn't *faster*. A performance issue even back then was that EF would try to prepare statements when a context was used for the first time. People that *mis*used contexts as if they were a model of the entire database found that startup was slow. THe solution was to *not* use One Big Context. A DbContext roughly represents a Unit of Work or Use Case  and should only contain the classes it needs for that UoW. So `a couple of hundred tables` but how many contexts?

Comment: Since it takes 1 minute, did you try using SQL Server Extended Events or Profiler to see what's actually going on?

Comment: All tables have a context. All contexts are used in the code.
The project with EF4 start up in a few seconds.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52405059/1466046)

Comment: What does `all tables have a context` mean? 100 contexts? That's not a good idea either. Again, what does the profiler show? What is the code doing? You're asking people to guess what your database schema, EF model and context configuration look like

Comment: Are you using .edmx file or POCO classes?